# Custom text position on image click

Tags: html, css, image, onclick, click

does anyone know How I can position the text on an image once its been clicked,

I have attached an image below of how I would like it displayed,

[image]

```js
function showSpoiler(obj) {
  var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  if (inner.style.display == "none")
    inner.style.display = "";
  else
    inner.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body,
input {
  font-family: "Trebuchet ms", arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}

.spoiler {}

.spoiler .inner {}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="http://konpakuto.com/logo.jpg />
  <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    This is a spoiler!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried and what part does not work as expected ?

Comment: I have tried to move the text above the image so that when its clicked it display's either lock/unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can put the **.inner** class div above your image for starters.
- Make use of absolute positioning on the .inner class, so the image doesn't shift down when .inner is displayed and align it to the center.
- Shift the *image with some m**argin from the top*** to make some space for the text.
- For toggling between unlock and lock, you can make use of a *flag/count variable* which changes value on each click.

.

```
.spoiler {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.spoiler img {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.spoiler .inner {
font-size:20pt;
position:absolute;
color:white;
top:5px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```js
var count=0;
function showSpoiler(obj) {
  var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  if (count==0){
  inner.textContent = "UNLOCK";
  setTimeout(function(){inner.textContent = "";},2000);
  count=1;
  } 
  else{
  inner.textContent = "LOCK";
  setTimeout(function(){inner.textContent = "";},2000);
  count=0;
  }
    
}
```

```css
body,
input {
  font-family: "Trebuchet ms", arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
}

.spoiler {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.spoiler img {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.spoiler .inner {
font-size:20pt;
position:absolute;
color:white;
top:5px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="inner">
    LOCK
  </div>
  <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="http://konpakuto.com/logo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly it! now I just need to add a toggle button so that it switches between lock and unlock! do you know the best way of achieving this?

Comment: @harry No problem :) Don't forget to rate it up and mark it as accepted. Cheers. And if you want to have the content initially locked and then unlocked, instead of using display:none and all, just change the innerhtml of .inner using javascript.

Comment: just one last thing, whats the best way to achieve the toggle on click?

Comment: @harry Editing, sec.

Comment: @harry Updated.

Comment: @harry No problem

Comment: One more thing @highdef how do I have it so the text disappears after a few seconds once its clicked?

Comment: @harry Updated, you can make use of setTimeout(function(){inner.textContent = "";},2000); which will change the inner text to blank after 2 seconds.

Comment: Perfect thanks you! Also is there a way to fix the text on the image so it always stays just above the image I keep repositioning the text but it never sits directly on top of the image! Thanks

Comment: @harry Adjust the margin-top of the image to your needs

Comment: Awesome!! Don't suppose you have time to look at my latest question trying to get all of this done before the new year 

Comment: @harry It's already new years for me and there's plenty of people on stack overflow that will help you out :)

Comment: Haha happy new year then! And no worries thanks for your help man!

Comment: @harry No problem. Happy New Year